# datetime2 "number too big" error when eliminating separators

Tags: errors, number, datetime2

I'm trying to produce a date/time output as a string of numbers without any separators: yyyymmddHHMMss. I was able to use the yearmonthsep= and other options in datetime2 to eliminate any colons or dashes between the numbers, however when setting the 4th of these package options, I get "Error: Number too big. \end{document}". I'm able to individually type \today or \DTMcurrenttime, but can't put them together as I want in the header. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[yearmonthsep=,monthdaysep=,hourminsep=,minsecsep=]{datetime2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\fancyhf{}

\topmargin=-0.45in
\evensidemargin=0in
\oddsidemargin=0in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.0in
\headsep=0.25in

\newcommand{\noteTitle}{\today \DTMcurrenttime}
\newcommand{\notesAuthor}{AUTHOR}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\noteTitle}
\rhead{\notesAuthor}

\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Section 1}
    
    \section*{Section 2}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug. Workaround is to insert `\relax` after the `\today`

Comment: Oh, interesting command. That worked, thanks!

Comment: I went report a bug at https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php (pending review). Hopefully fixed in next version.